# Calling javascript on document.Load() passing C# parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, dom-events

I have a JavaScript function that I need to run.  It takes some parameters.  The actual parameters are in a collection in my view model.  This JavaScript function needs to be called as many times as there are elements in the collection, with the elements of the collection as the respective parameters each time.

This function needs to be called when the document loads.  So, I thought I should put the calls to this function in `document.ready`.  The problem is that I don't know how to loop through my C# collection and generate Javascript at the same time.  Do you know how I can achieve this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can serialize your view model to JSON and render it inside script block in your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var collection = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

        $.each(collection, function (i, value) {
           yourFunction(value);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

First Step: 
Convert the collection to JSON and put it in viewbag :

```
ViewBag.Collection = Json.Encode(your - collection)
```

Second Step:

Use that collection from the Viewbag

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var collection = @Viewbag.collection;
});
</script>
```

Third Step: 

Use that Object to iterate through it and do stuff in that :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var collection = @Viewbag.collection;
    $.each(collection , function() {
     //Do Stuff
    });
    });

 </script>
```